# How to unit test program interacting with block devices

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a program that interacts with and changes block devices (/dev/sda and such) on linux. I'm using various external commands (mostly commands from the fdisk and GNU fdisk packages) to control the devices. I have made a class that serves as the interface for most of the basic actions with block devices (for information like: What size is it? Where is it mounted? etc.)

Here is one such method querying the size of a partition:

```
def get_drive_size(device):
    """Returns the maximum size of the drive, in sectors.

    :device the device identifier (/dev/sda and such)"""

    query_proc = subprocess.Popen(["blockdev", "--getsz", device], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    #blockdev returns the number of 512B blocks in a drive
    output, error = query_proc.communicate()
    exit_code = query_proc.returncode
    if exit_code != 0:
        raise Exception("Non-zero exit code", str(error, "utf-8")) #I have custom exceptions, this is slight pseudo-code

    return int(output) #should always be valid
```

So this method accepts a block device path, and returns an integer. The tests will run as root, since this entire program will end up having to run as root anyway.

Should I try and test code such as these methods? If so, how? I could try and create and mount image files for each test, but this seems like a lot of overhead, and is probably error-prone itself. It expects block devices, so I cannot operate directly on image files in the file system.

I could try mocking, as some answers suggest, but this feels inadequate. It seems like I start to test the implementation of the method, if I mock the Popen object, rather than the output. Is this a correct assessment of proper unit-testing methodology in this case?

I am using python3 for this project, and I have not yet chosen a unit-testing framework. In the absence of other reasons, I will probably just use the default unittest framework included in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the mock module (I think it's part of the unittest module now in Python 3).

It enables you to run tests without the need to depened in any external resources while giving you control over how the mocks interact with your code.

I would start from the docs in [Voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/)

Here's an example:

```
import unittest2 as unittest
import mock

class GetDriveSizeTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):

  @mock.patch('path/to/original/file.subprocess.Popen')
  def test_a_scenario_with_mock_subprocess(self, mock_popen):
    mock_popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = ('Expected_value', '')
    mock_popen.return_value.returncode = '0'
    self.assertEqual('expected_value', get_drive_size('some device'))
```

Comment: I'm using non-python commands in my method. How do I mock for these system commands?

Comment: You can mock subprocess.Popen and then tell it to return a value which fits the scenario you wish to test. The point of mock is that you don't need to actually interact with anything other than the code you're testing. You can have the mock return any output you want, or even raise an Exception when called.

Comment: I guess that could work, though the Popen object isn't passed into the method. How would I insert the Popen mock? I don't want to make it a parameter, that would defeat the purpose of the method.

Comment: In your unittest, apply a patch to subprocess.Popen and then set a return value for it, as well as a return value for its communicate method and return code property. I'll add a simple example