# Creating a Fake Reality: Testing Using Virtual Block Devices

Tags: linux, testing, device

I'm writing a program that edits partitions of block devices (/dev/sda and such) on linux. I've got the programs to work fairly well, and I have unit tested my code using mocks (as worked through in a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888013/how-to-unit-test-program-interacting-with-block-devices)), and now I would like to test my code on actually devices.

The code copies a partition table from one drive to another, possibly shrinking the partition table if needed. Afterwards, it copies the files from one drive to another. So I want to test my drive using drives of various relative sizes. Finally it makes the new drive bootable, essentially cloning the device.Unfortunately, I don't have physical drives in the correct sizes to test this program within a reasonable time limit. I am using python to write the program.

I have been testing using .img (created using `dd`) files and various tools to mount them, but  apparently VirtualBox can't run these in a VM, so I can't really test if they boot. I also tried mounting .vdi files using `qemu-nbd`, but sgdisk and similar tools can edit partitions on those. I even tried mounting the .img file and using a `convertfromraw`  command to try and mount that way. However, grub failed to properly boot and could not read the filesystems on the hard drive. (typing `ls (hd0)` returned `No such filesystem...`)

What can I use to make virtual disks of (practically) any size, which I can edit on my Linux system then boot from virtual box?

Note that I'm not trying to unit test. These aren't intended to be automatic tests, so it doesn't have to be something that the computer can easily do by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Using .img files worked best in the end. In order to create your img files use `dd`.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=my-test.img bs=1M count=500 #Creates a 500 MB image file
```

Mount the file using losetup

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 my-test.img #Mounts on loop device loop0
sudo partprobe /dev/loop0 #creates block files for any partitions on the image
```

Apply whatever commands you would like; edit partitions with `sgdisk` or even mount partitions and edit data. If you want your test drive to be bootable, be sure to apply the proper bootloader commands (`grub-install` and such). Then to make it usable in VirtualBox, use the following command.

```
VBoxManage convertdd my-test.img my-test.vdi
```

This will convert the file to something usable by VirtualBox. If the file was not created by dd, you may need to use other `VBoxManage` commands to convert it to a raw type.

Finally, simple create a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox using the .vdi file and test to your heart's content.